# icefaces javascript with partial update does not get evaluated

Tags: jquery, icefaces, icefaces-3

I use `ace:tabset` that creates partial ajax updates for the chosen `ace:tabPane`. It gets the content of the chosen pane with ajax.

However components shown from the partial ajax update contain `<script type="text/javascript" ...` tags, which do not get evaluated by any browser.

This way I cannot use for example `ace:dialog` that comes from my partial update because it has it's own js function to show itself defined in a  tag, that is in fact does not get evaluated, where all other dom elements of this partial update are in fact inserted in the dom tree.

I must not be the only one with this problem. I use Icefaces and icefaces-ace 3.0.1

Thanks